# Windows Phone 8 Maps XAMLParseException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, here-api

I got a simple XAML script with a map object in it that should not give any problems. Yet, when debugging the app I'm getting a XAMLParseException thrown. I've added xmlns declaration as needed and can't understand why the exception is thrown.

This is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <maps:Map />
</Grid>
```

The exception detail:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map' [Line: 34 Position: 28]
  Source=System.Windows
  LineNumber=34
  LinePosition=28
  InnerException: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
       HResult=-2147024891
       Message=Access to Maps requires ID_CAP_MAP to be defined in the manifest
       Source=Microsoft.Phone.Maps
       InnerException:
```

Comment: It would really help if you could show us the actual exception.

Comment: Added in the question itself. Understand it has something to do with this ID_Cap_Map, yet don't really understand what it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after making a few minutes research once I got to the exception detail I've ran into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033(v=vs.105).aspx) guide and just added the ID_Cap_Map capabillity which fixed the issue.

Comment: thnks Raz harush, i was also nailed with this issue